# How can I serve static files with an index that has a base href in Node Express?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm using `express.static(path)` to serve static files (a built Angular application `dist` directory). I can't find out how to serve them when the app is using a non-default `base-href`.

I have a `distStatic` variable that works correctly:

`const distStatic = express.static(distPath);`

Previously, without the `base-href`, this worked:

```
app.use('/', distStatic);
app.use('/*', distStatic);
```

Going to `localhost:port` worked. Now, when I build with `--base-href=/master/`, I have this:

```
app.use('/master', distStatic);
app.use('/master/*', distStatic);
```

Going to `localhost:port/master` loads the index... But every call to something within distStatic always returns the index.

Comment: just use `app.use('/master', distStatic);`

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful when using base-href. Because of any API calls inside the static must be changed to `/master/path-to-api/`.

I believe calls inside is hitting `/path-to-api/` which is a 404 which is being handled to go to index.